# VBA (Excel) 2010: specific script how-to, dealing with range comparisons

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have 3 columns that follow these rules:

- Any cell in Col A may be empty, otherwise it contains a string.
- If a row in Col A is empty, that row in Col's B and C will be empty.
- If a row in Col A is populated, That row in Col B will be populated with an integer, and that row in Col C may be empty or have a "1".

I need a script that, for each cell in Col A,

1. Checks the string in that cell and looks for all identical strings in Col A.
2. For each row containing said matching string, checks Col C for a "1"
3. For each row where **both** of the above are true, sum the values in Col B and replace each of them with that sum.

So for example, this:

```
A B C
x 1  
x 2  
z 2 1
y 1 1
y 2 1

y 1 
z 2 1
z 1 1
```

Should become this:

```
A B C
x 1
x 2
z 5 1
y 3 1
y 3 1

y 1
z 5 1
z 5 1
```

So 3 different strings are found in Col A, (x y and z). Duplicates of x are found but the values in col B are not summed because there was no "1" in Col C. Dupes of y are found, but only those with a "1" to the right are summed. All dupes of z found have a "1", so all are summed.

What's the best way to do this? Please let me know if I need to clarify something about this question (I know it's convoluted, but I spent a lot of time trying to make it as clear as possible haha).

Comment: What's stopping you from reaching your goal here?  Exactly which part are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula should do the job : assuming the data are found in A:C

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",IF(ISBLANK(C2),B2, SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,1)))
```

The outer `IF` display nothing when `column A` is empty.
The inner `IF` display`column B` when `column C` is empty.
The `SUMIFS` will add up`column B` where `column A` is the same(as current row) and when `column C` is 1.

Comment: Well, I really need this in a VBA script.  Also I can't assume length of columns, this script will have to work without knowing the column lengths.  Thank you for this reply though, it is a great jumping off point.

Comment: thank you, I can certainly use this.  If I come up with some VBA I'll post it back here.